# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') at createProductCards

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, slider, undefined

I m trying to make an ecommerce website with javascript and I encountered this problem when I was trying to make a slider with products. Here is the code:

```
const searchKey = decodeURI(location.pathname.split('/').pop());

const searchSpanElement = document.querySelector('#search-key');
searchSpanElement.innerHTML = searchKey;

getProducts(searchKey).then(data => createProductCards(data, '.card-container'));

const getProducts = (tag) => {
   return fetch('/get-products', {
      method: "post",
      headers: new Headers({"Content-Type": "application/json"}),
      body: JSON.stringify({tag: tag})
   })
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(data => {
      return data;
   })
}


const createProductSlider = (data, parent, title) => {
   let slideContainer = document.querySelector(`${parent}`);

   slideContainer.innerHTML +=
       ` <section class="product">
             <h2 class="product-category">${title}</h2>
             <button class="pre-btn"><img src="../css/img/arrow.png" alt=""></button>
             <button class="nxt-btn"><img src="../css/img/arrow.png" alt=""></button>
             ${createProductCards(data)}
         </section> `

   setupSlidingEffect();
}

const createProductCards = (data, parent) => {
   // here parent is for search product
   let start = '<div class="product-container">';
   let middle = '';  // this will contain card HTML
   let end = '</div>';

   for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       if(data[i].id != decodeURI(location.pathname.split('/').pop())) {
         middle += 
         ` <div class="product-card">
               <div class="product-image">
                   <span class="discount-tag">${data[i].discount}% off</span>
                   <img src="${data[i].images[0]}" class="product-thumb" alt="">
               </div>
               <div class="product-info" onclick="location.href = '/products/${data[i].id}'">
                   <h2 class="product-brand">${data[i].name}</h2>
                   <p class="product-short-des">${data[i].shortDes}</p>
                   <span class="price">$${data[i].sellPrice}</span> <span class="actual-price">$${data[i].actualPrice}</span>
               </div>
           </div> `
       }
   }

   if(parent) {
       let cardContainer = document.querySelector(parent);
       cardContainer.innerHTML = start + middle + end;
   } else {
       return start + middle + end;
   }
}
```

I see in console that the problem must be on this line, at images array:
`<img src="${data[i].images[0]}" class="product-thumb" alt="">`

I expect it to show me the products slider after i enter the search key in the search box

Comment: It tells you that `data[i].images` is undefined and therefore cannot access the 0 index. Without your server response (json) we can't tell much about it.

Comment: Seemingly `data[i]` does not have an `images` property ... Set a breakpoint in your `getData` function and check for all elements in the `data` array if they have an `images` property and if yes, if it's different from undefined. For at least of one of the elements, this is not true

Comment: Debug it: `for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { console.log(i, data[i].images, data[i]);`

Comment: 0 undefined 'n'
1 undefined 'o'
2 undefined ' '
3 undefined 'p'
4 undefined 'r'
5 undefined 'o' 6 undefined 'd'
7 undefined 'u'
8 undefined 'c'
9 undefined 't'
10 undefined 's'
0 undefined 'n'
1 undefined 'o'
2 undefined ' '
3 undefined 'p'
4 undefined 'r'
5 undefined 'o'
6 undefined 'd'
7 undefined 'u'
8 undefined 'c'
9 undefined 't'
10 undefined 's'      This is what i get in console, after debugging